# If then else Python

Tags: python, if-statement

If I have the following dataset how can I create a new field called `Article_Title` that will use this logic:

if the title is not `NaN` then copy the contents into `Article_Title`
else if `thread_title` is not `NaN` then copy the contents into `Article_Title`

[image: Screenshot of table]

Comment: Just do it exactly as you explained it will work

Comment: NaN is a floating-point value; it literally stands for "Not A Number". Why would it ever be in a column of string values?

Comment: blank instead of NaN then. What code do I need?

Comment: are you basically asking _how to write if-statement in python in general_?

Comment: yes that's what I am asking Karina. Looking for guidance on the code to use

Comment: @EllenTaylor, do you have dataframe or excel file?

Comment: I have a dataframe

Comment: For that it doesn't need any if statement, you can just add both column (see answer from user1740577). Or why do you think you need an if-statement? In case both are empty and/or both have values?